# how to do weighted average in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a few rows (30 rows) and many columns. I wanna find a weighted sum for each row. that is I wanna multiply row `j` with `a_j` and sum with others. It is easy to do manually but I wanna do that as a function. is it possible?

data

```
index c1. c2.   c3. 
a    1    2     3
b    2    10    0
c   3    2      3
d   3     3     3
e   2    1     0
```

I have the list of constant: `cons=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]`

I want a new row which gives me this as in `c1` column. for other column calculation is the same.

```
   new_col
   1*0.1  +  2*0.1 +    3*0.1 +3*0.4   +2*0.5
```

I did this

```
cons=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
for i in range(len(cons)):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        df.iloc[i,j]=df.iloc[i,j]*cons[i]


Error: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

why I have this error and how should I do the `sum` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with `sum`:

```
cons=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]

df = df.mul(cons, axis=0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
index
a    0.6
b    2.4
c    2.4
d    3.6
e    1.5
dtype: float64
```

If need sum per rows:

```
cons=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]

out = df.mul(cons, axis=0).sum(axis=0)
print (out)
c1.    3.6
c2.    4.5
c3.    2.4
dtype: float64

out = df.T.dot(cons)
print (out)
c1.    3.6
c2.    4.5
c3.    2.4
dtype: float64
```

EDIT: I think you need:

```
print (df)
       c1.  c2.  c3.
index               
a        1    2    3
b        2   10    0
c        3    2    3
d        3    3    3
e        2    1    0

cons=[0.1,0.2,0.3]
```

---

```
df1 = df.mul(cons, axis=1)
print (df1)
       c1.  c2.  c3.
index               
a      0.1  0.4  0.9
b      0.2  2.0  0.0
c      0.3  0.4  0.9
d      0.3  0.6  0.9
e      0.2  0.2  0.0

out = df1.sum(axis=1)
print (out)
index
a    1.4
b    2.2
c    1.6
d    1.8
e    0.4
dtype: float64

out = df.dot(cons)
print (out)
index
a    1.4
b    2.2
c    1.6
d    1.8
e    0.4
dtype: float64
```

Comment: sorry I made mistake I should sum each column. is it gonna be `sum(axis=0)`?

Comment: @elham - Why is 3 times mulitple by 0.1 and then by 0.4 and 0.5 ?

Comment: @elham - From your desription I edit answer. Can you test?